# How do bigger & smaller web devs test out their code before deployment?

Tags: php, html, hosting

I've been trying to learn more about PHP and more server-side code in general, and I hit a point where I realized that if I want to upgrade my website, I would need to take it down and copy the code while the users were online.

Furthermore, since I haven't launched my website yet, and unindexed by Google, it rarely gets any visits, so I'm free to upload and test out whatever I want using PHPStorm + FTP. But I realize that once I finish my project, and have users, I wouldn't want to change things while they were using them.

How do people write code and debug, and setup before deployment to verify that their website would function fine? Also, how would you copy over the code? Both from a large website (i.e. apple.com, cnn.com - websites that need to be on 24/7) vs. smaller blogs/websites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking about **[`Continuous Integration` / `Continuous Deployment`](https://www.atlassian.com/continuous-delivery/principles/continuous-integration-vs-delivery-vs-deployment)** ('`CI/CD`').

Basically you'll want to make use of a testing server to test your code on before the public get to see it. You deploy out your code to this server and test it thoroughly, confirming that everything is ready to go out to production. With more in-depth setups this testing can be automated with tools like **[Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/)** or **[TestComplete](https://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/overview/)**.

In theory, you should be deploying a '**[release cut](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/)**' of a **[GitFlow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)** workflow out to your testing environment. This ensures that all planned changes have been finalised and are ready to ultimately be shipped out to the public without any other changes getting mixed up in the release.

When you're finally ready to ship out to production, you'll want to *plan* the release, and meet with any associated parties. I'd recommend a proper release checklist, where you confirm that all of the additional features are working as expected, and that you're not accidentally removing any existing functionality (**[regression testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing)**).

Note that a deployment out to production should have absolutely no differences to a deployment out to a test environment; the *only* thing that should be changing on the production environment is the server in which the environment is hosted, along with database configurations. This ensures that you're not accidentally testing / using any data that your customers might also interact with.

The production deployment itself *should* (essentially) just be a 'copy-paste' of the files to disk, and is often done with a Continuous Integration tool like **[Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/)** or **[TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)**. Assuming you only have a small website, this should be an almost instantaneous procedure, and shouldn't even require any downtime on your production environment. If the process is likely to take a while longer (such as with a complex deployment), you may want to implement a maintenance page. This will inform your users that you're working on the website, and let them know when they can expect functionality to resume.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a developer for an e-commerce website, when we were smaller (50-75 users online at a time) I would just use FTP eg, FileZilla to update the files I had changed with my latest edit, this would mean people would be served my changes and the website would not go down at all. For small edits, I would also just ssh in and manually edit the file if it needed to be done quickly.

Now we have grown much larger and have other developers (100-200 users at a time) to be fair I should be doing it this way before but I deploy directly from PHP storm/version control. I have working branches and once my work is ready to be deployed ill put it into the master branch.

Once the master branch has work pushed into it I have a script that checks for changes and clones the repo. (this happens automaticaly.)

Comment: EDIT: I also have a local test environment that myself and other people on my local network can use for testing. (this identical to the live environment)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to cover here, and some of it is opinion based *(which I will try to avoid)*.

> How do people write code and debug, and setup before deployment to verify that their website would function fine

There are many ways to create a local development site, but most modern approaches involve containers. Docker is the most popular, which allows you to create replicas of a web server, database, etc. and run them locally on your machine. You can also use virtual machines to create a replica of your production server, or simply install the needed packages (i.e. php, apache, mysql) on your local machine.

Larger companies will typically have a QA (Quality Assurance) department who test all changes before they are deployed. As others have mentioned, some of this can be automated with testing software. When there is a QA team, you have a staging server where changes are first deployed. Once the changes pass QA and any automated tests (i.e. PHPUnit) they are deployed to production.

> Also, how would you copy over the code?

This can get very opinionated, so I will just give you different options and not argue for or against any of them:

- Use a service like rsync to transfer the files. With this approach, you typically have a staging server where you checkout your code from version control *(or manually copy it if you aren't using version control)*, run any build scripts such as composer, gulp, etc., and then sync the files to production. In a larger setup, you wrap all of this into a script to automate it.
- If you are using version control *(let's use Git as an example)*, you can also pull the code down to your production server *(as apposed to pushing it up to production)*, by running `git pull` on your production server. This will get all the latest changes, then you run any build scripts such as composer, gulp, etc.
- There are also tools for continue integration (i.e. Jenkins) that facilitate a lot of the work mentioned above. You can go as far as setting up hooks on GitHub, so your code is automatically built and deployed when you merge into `master`.
- On a small or personal project, it might be simpler to just use FTP and manually transfer the files.